# Dimensions validation in Laravel 5.8 is not working

Tags: php, laravel, image

I am using the following code to validate the dimensions of the image in Laravel 5.8 ([link to following code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-dimensions)):

`'profile_image' => 'required|dimensions:width=300,height=500'`

but I am getting the error eventhough I attached exact 300x500 image, look at the following code:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($request->profile_image);
$messages = [
    'profile_image.dimensions' => "Profile image must be 300x500 resolution (current is {$width}x{$height})."
];
$request->validate([
    'profile_image' => 'required|dimensions:width=300,height=500',
], $messages);
```

I am getting this **"Profile image must be 300x500 resolution (current is 300x500)".**

I also tried `min_width=300,min_height=500` and `max_width=300,max_height=500` but not working.

> **Image is in base64 format** *(I think it doesn't matter)*

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Image is in base64 format (According to me it doesn't matter)" But have you tried a normal binary image? Because a base64 image has no metadata attached afaik

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
'profile_image' => [
    'required',
    Rule::dimensions()->width(300)->height(500)
]
```